# Inscribed angle theorem using complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to prove the inscribed angle theorem using complex numbers. Let $ABC$ be a triangle inscribed in a circle and denote the corresponding complex number to every point by its lower case letter.

Let $\alpha=\angle BAC$ so we want to show that $\omega :=\angle BOC =2\alpha$. Where $O$ is the center of the circle.

We know $\alpha=\arg\left(\frac{b-a}{c-a}\right)$ and $\omega = \arg(b/c)=b/c$ (since $a,b$ and $c$ are on the unit circle and $O=0$) so we want to show $$2\alpha=\frac{b}{c}$$
Which I think is equivalent to showing that
$$\frac{b-a}{c-a}\cdot \frac{c}{b}=\frac{bc-ac}{bc-ab}$$ is a real number. But I don't see how we can show that.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: see the edit. @FadeelKhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Unit circle with three points]

Choose axes and units so that your circle is a unit circle, two points on the circle are $z$ and $\overline{z}$ with $z=e^{i \theta}$, and the third point on the circle is $w$.  The angle from the origin to $z$ and $\overline{z}$ is the argument of $z / \overline{z}$.

But
$$\frac{z}{\overline{z}} = \frac{z}{\overline{z}} \cdot \frac{z}{z} = \frac{z^2}{z \overline{z}} = \frac{z^2}{1} = e^{2i \theta}$$
since $z \overline{z} = |z|^2 =1$ on the unit circle.  So the angle is $2 \theta$.

The angle from $w$ to $z$ and $\overline{z}$ is the argument of
$$v = \frac{z-w}{\overline{z}-w}$$
Since $z=e^{i \theta}$, the argument of $v$ is also $\theta$ provided $v/z$ is real, i.e. has zero imaginary part. Twice the imaginary part is
$$\begin{align}
\frac{v}{z} - \overline{\left( \frac{v}{z} \right)} &= \frac{v}{z} - \frac{\overline{v}}{\overline{z}} \\ &= \frac{1}{z} \cdot \frac{z-w}{\overline{z}-w} - \frac{1}{\overline{z}} \cdot \frac{\overline{z}-\overline{w}}{z-\overline{w}} \\
&= \frac{z-w}{1-wz} - \frac{\overline{z}-\overline{w}}{1-\overline{w}\overline{z}} \\
&= \frac{(z-w)(1-\overline{w}\overline{z}) - (1-wz)(\overline{z}-\overline{w})}{(1-wz)(1-\overline{w}\overline{z})} \\
&= 0
\end{align} \\
$$
after a little algebra, keeping in mind that $w\overline{w} = z\overline{z}=1$.  This completes the proof.

Comment: I think your answer lacks generality, as you have taken the third point to be -1, while it can be anything on the unit circle.

Comment: @FadeelKhan I think you're right.  Let me think about it.

Comment: @FadeelKhan OK, I think I have fixed it now by taking the third point as arbitrary on the unit circle.

Comment: You can't just assume that the third point is $\bar{z}$

Comment: @PNT you can. First you take a random point $z$, after that you choose your axes such that one of the other points is $\bar {z}$, and the third point is again some random point $w$. This is general.

Comment: So we can achieve every possible triangle on the circle by constantly moving $z$ along the circle (of course $w$ is free) @FadeelKhan

Comment: Yes, that's right. In fact you just need to move it such that $\arg(z) \in (0, \pi/2]$

Comment: @FadeelKhan see my answer it's much simpler

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a very simple method to show that $$\left(\frac{b-a}{c-a}\right)^2\cdot \frac{c}{b}$$ is real. We know $x= \bar x \iff x$ is real and that's exactly what we're going to show here since $$ x= \left(\frac{b-a}{c-a}\right)^2\cdot \frac{c}{b} $$ and $\bar x=x$ You can check that easily since $\bar a =1/a$ and that's because $a$ is on the unit circle

Comment: Yes, this is much more efficient than my answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

> Which I think is equivalent to showing that
> $$\frac{b-a}{c-a}\cdot \frac{c}{b}=\frac{bc-ac}{bc-ab}$$ is a real number...

You missed the 2 which was there in this equation. $$2\arg\left(\frac{b-a}{c-a}\right)=\frac{b}{c}$$

Thus, you would have to prove that $$\left(\frac{b-a}{c-a}\right)^2\cdot \frac{c}{b}$$ is a real number.

Though I have taken a different approach, as follows.

---

Let $a = e^{i\theta_1}$, $b = e^{i\theta_2}$ and $c = e^{i\theta_3}$, and let $\triangle ABC$ be in the anticlockwise sense (as is in the diagram of the OP). Let $\angle BOC = \alpha$, $\angle COA = \beta$ and $\angle AOB = \gamma$ (Note that $\alpha$ is $\angle BOC$, not $\angle BAC$ as is in the OP). We have

$\frac{b}{a} = e^{i(\theta_2 - \theta_1)} = e^{i\gamma} \\
\Rightarrow b=ae^{i\gamma} \\
\text{Similarly, } c=ae^{-i\beta}$

Now computing $\arg\left(\dfrac{b-a}{c-a}\right)$

$\begin{align}
\arg\left(\dfrac{b-a}{c-a}\right) & = \arg\left(\dfrac{ae^{i\gamma}-a}{ae^{-i\beta}-a}\right) \\ & = \arg\left(\dfrac{1 - e^{i\gamma}}{1 - e^{-i\beta}}\right) \\ & = \arg\left(\dfrac{(1-\cos(\gamma)) - i\sin(\gamma)}{(1-\cos(\beta)) + i\sin(\beta)}\right) \\ & = \arg\left(\dfrac{2\sin^2(\frac{\gamma}{2}) - 2i\sin(\frac{\gamma}{2})\cos(\frac{\gamma}{2})}{2\sin^2(\frac{\beta}{2}) + 2i\sin(\frac{\beta}{2})\cos(\frac{\beta}{2})}\right) \\ & = \arg\left(\dfrac{\sin(\frac{\gamma}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\beta}{2})}\cdot\dfrac{\sin(\frac{\gamma}{2}) - i\cos(\frac{\gamma}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\beta}{2}) + i\cos(\frac{\beta}{2})}\right) \\ & = \arg\left(\dfrac{\sin(\frac{\gamma}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\beta}{2})}\cdot\dfrac{e^{i(\frac{\gamma}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2})}}{e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\beta}{2})}}\right) \\ & = \arg\left(\dfrac{\sin(\frac{\gamma}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\beta}{2})}\cdot e^{i(\frac{\beta + \gamma}{2} - \pi)}\right) \\ & =  \dfrac{\beta + \gamma}{2} - \pi \\ & = \dfrac{2\pi - \alpha}{2} - \pi \\ & = -\dfrac{\alpha}{2}
\end{align}$

And $\arg\left(\dfrac{b}{c}\right) = \arg\left(e^{i(\theta_2 - \theta_3)}\right) = -\alpha$

Comment: You can save yourself a little bit of writing by placing one vertex at $ \ e^{ \ i \ \pi} \ $ without affecting the generality of the proof.  (I had written out such an argument, then saw that it otherwise didn't differ significantly from yours.)  Although it may not be as concise as some of the other posted proofs, it is interesting to see that the circular trigonometric identities, as properties of the complex exponential function, in a sense implicitly carry the inscribed angle theorem.